# Making emulsion out of slaughterhouse waste

Tags: plant-care, compost, fertilizer, compost-tea

I have previously made fish emulsion to fertilize a small greywater garden; pretty much sealing fish waste (entrails, bones, skin) into oxygen-free plastic containers and leaving it for 6 months to a year, and using the diluted 'tea' as a fertilizer. I've just moved to a new island where fish waste is not that readily available, but there is a small slaughterhouse which primarily slaughters goats. Presumably the same process would still work using goat offal? Are there any other factors I need to consider?

Edit: I should specify that this won't be for foods which will be eaten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work.  The stink will be different, but presumably you had a way to deal with that.

Locally we had a fish plant that would run all the waste through a chopper, then dry it into fish chips.  Chips were ground to powder, then pressed for oil.  Oil and meal were sold as chicken and turkey feed.

East coast aboriginals would often plant a fish under a pumpkin/squash to provide nitrogen for the pumpkin plant.  Don't know how they kept the dogs from digging it up.  Could be bad news if you have a local rat population.  In principle it should work for offal too.

In general, I think you would get more out of the offal if you grind it up, and rototil it into the soil in fall, then cover with leaves.

---

As a different outlook:  The slaughter house is missing a bet:  Should be grinding and freezing this stuff as cat/dog food.